# How to get Monday 00:00 of current week? Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, date, swift3

I'm trying to return Monday 00:00 from my date. This is my code:

```
func getMonday(myDate: Date) -> Date {
    let cal = Calendar.current
    let comps = cal.dateComponents([.weekOfYear, .yearForWeekOfYear], from: myDate)
    let beginningOfWeek = cal.date(from: comps)!
    return beginningOfWeek
}
```

My problem is that it does not return Monday 00:00 , but Saturday 22:00.

Example:

```
    let monday1 = getMonday(myDate: date) //date is: 2016-10-04 17:00:00
    print(monday1) //Prints: 2016-10-01 22:00:00 (Saturday)
```

My question is:

**How to return Monday 00:00 from `myDate`**?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Printing a Date always uses GMT, so I assume that the output actually is `2016-10-01 22:00:00 +0000`, which is `2016-10-02 00:00:00` in your time zone, that is Sunday. `Calendar` has a `firstWeekday` property which controls which day is considered the first in the week, you might have to set that to 2=Monday.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your code returns the *first day* in the given week, that may be
a Sunday or Monday (or perhaps some other day), depending on your locale.

If you want Monday considered to be the first weekday then set

```
cal.firstWeekday = 2
```

If you want the Monday of the given week, independent of what the
start of the week is, then set `comps.weekday = 2`:

```
func getMonday(myDate: Date) -> Date {
    let cal = Calendar.current
    var comps = cal.dateComponents([.weekOfYear, .yearForWeekOfYear], from: myDate)
    comps.weekday = 2 // Monday
    let mondayInWeek = cal.date(from: comps)!
    return mondayInWeek
}
```

Note that printing a `Date` always uses the GMT time zone,
you'll need a *date formatter* to print the result according to your local time zone. Example:

```
let df = DateFormatter()
df.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"

let now = Date()
print(df.string(from: now)) // 2016-10-02 20:16

let monday1 = getMonday(myDate: now)
print(df.string(from: monday1)) // 2016-09-26 00:00
```

Comment: A small typo is found. The correct variable name is "firstWeekday" not "firstWeekDay".

Comment: You set the value of `cal.firstWeekday`, but you don't set that value in `getMonday()`. I believe that causes the `getMonday()` code to work incorrectly. From my tests you need to both set the value of `cal.firstWeekday` and `comps.weekday`.

Comment: @ThomasW: I may have expressed myself badly. By setting `cal.firstWeekday` you control what the calendar considers to be the first day in the week. As an example, with `cal.firstWeekday = 7` for Saturday (and not setting `comps.weekday`) the function will return the preceding Saturday (today is Thursday). On the other hand, if you set `comps.weekday = 7` (but not `cal.firstWeekday`) then the function will return the Saturday in the current week, that is the next Saturday.